# Python list copy

Tags: python, list

I know that a list L can be copied by doing L[:]. But I face an issue that I do not understand why.

```
src = [1,2,3]
dest = [[5,6,7]]
dest.append(src[:].append(4))
dest
[[5, 6, 7], None]
```

In the above sample, the src list is not copied to dest (see None) when I tried to copy and append 4 to it.

```
dest.append(src[:])
dest
[[5, 6, 7], None, [1, 2, 3]]
```

As seen in the above snippet, if I add simply add the list (to dest) without any append attempt, it gets inserted.
Any idea?

Comment: What is the end result you need? [[5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3]]? or [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]?

Comment: @zengr, [[5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4]]. The problem is `append` doesn't return the modified list (it returns None).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What `append` tries to do is to append data on the given list and returns `None`.

That's why you will see `None` at the end of `dest`.

The following code should do what you want:

```
dest.append(src + [4])
```

Answer (score 3):

Functions/methods that modify their arguments/object inplace should return `None`. It is a common convention in Python. For example, `.append()`, `.extend()`, `random.shuffle()`; a notable exception is `.pop()`.

As [@qiao already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8951434/4279) you could use:

```
dest.append(src + [4])
```

Or

```
dest += [src + [4]]
```

`src + [4]` creates a new list: `[1,2,3,4]` so you don't need to make an explicit `src` copy.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand. Thanks Rob and Sebastian.

Comment: Question, do you know why such a convention exists? Maybe it's because I'm also used to Javascript, but returning `self` seems like it would be so much more useful than `None`. Is it just a preference of the BDFL or something?

Comment: It is intended to ensure that you avoid mistakes that result from accidentally using a mutating method without realizing that it mutates. For example, if `list#sort` returned the list, then you could call `foo(my_list.sort())` by mistake (when you should have written `foo(sorted(my_list))`), and then have problems because `my_list` is still sorted after the call (as opposed to having `foo` work with a sorted copy).

Comment: @voithos: [Command Query Separation](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html) has a wider application domain than [Fluent Interface](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) (that often implemented via method chaining). Python is not very suitable for method chaining due to its limited `lambda` support and its preference to explicit code blocks. Though `sqlalchemy`'s [Query](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html) is a successful example of such approach. A negative example could be [`asq`](http://code.google.com/p/asq/) that emulates LINQ in Python.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Wonderful! I knew there was a reason! I hadn't heard of Command Query Separation, but it makes sense. Thank you for enlightening me on this.